# Android Fondo de Spinner Dialog

Tags: java, android

Tengo el siguiente spinner

```
           <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
            android:id="@+id/origin_account"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:spinnerMode="dialog"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:popupBackground="#E6E6E6"
            android:textColor="@color/light_grey"/>
```

el codigo Java es el siguiente

```
 final  ArrayAdapter<Account> dataAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<Account>(TransferOwnAccountActivityStep1.this,R.layout.spinner_custom,R.id.text1,Destino);
            dataAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_custom);
            spinner_ocupaciones.setAdapter(dataAdapter2);
```

El Spinner Cumstom es

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/text1"
style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
android:singleLine="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:textAlignment="textStart"
android:background="@drawable/redondo"
android:drawableEnd="@drawable/flechaabajooo"/>
```

y el redondo.xml es

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<size android:width="200dp"
    android:height="30dp"></size>
<corners android:radius="5dp"></corners>
<solid android:color="#E6E6E6"></solid>
```

el tema viene que al presionar el spinner en modo DIALOGO  me aparece asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

me gustaria poder cambiarle el fondo blanco al color que yo quiera , ya probe con

```
 android:popupBackground="#E6E6E6"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agrega en tu archivo colors.xml el siguiente recurso:

```
 <color name="fondo_dialogo">#E6E6E6</color>
```

después de mostrar el diálogo, puedes cambiar el color del fondo mediante esta opción:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
AlertDialog alert = alertDialog.create();
...
...
//Muestra diálogo.
alert.show(); 

//Define color a fondo de diálogo.
alert.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.fondo_dialogo);
```

Este es un ejemplo de un `AlertDialog` con fondo verde:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ese " alert " que se supone que es , Ya que el spinner no le puedo poner esa propiedades , mi dialogo no es un alert un es SpinnerMode = Dialog

Comment: "alert" hace referencia a spinner en modo dialog, por lo que entendí.

Comment: Bruno obtienes alert a partir de  alertDialog.create(); , @L.Ronquillo  agregué más info para que sea entendible :D

Comment: @Jorgesys pero lo que él está usando es un spinner  que se muestra en modo de díalogo, ¿funciona igual?

Comment: @L.Ronquillo exacto, de hecho la imagen que agrego es un  AlertDialog con un ListView, el fondo se pinta de verde.